# How to name sheets based on names typed in cells on summary sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have very limited knowledge of google sheets and would appreciate any and all help.

I have created a google sheet with multiple sheets.  I would like to have the names that are typed in the cells for student names name the following sheets.

Thank you.

Here is a link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pOOwg5HLGXVg9XynJBGcVWjqnCV6xZSmMX38hZZgmvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

How about following script?

```
function sample() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var summarysheet = ss.getSheetByName('Put name of summary sheet name');
  var names = summarysheet.getRange('a4:a38').getValues();
  names.forEach(function(e, i){
    ss.getSheets()[i + 1].setName(e);
  });
}
```

I thought that it is very important the correspondence of names of summary sheet and each sheet. So conditions to use this sample script is as follows.

1. If you change the arrangement of sheets, the correspondence of names of summary sheet and each sheet cannot be done.
2. How do you think about the correspondence of names of summary sheet and number of sheets? Now, the number of sheets is 35 + (a summary sheet). This is same to (names of summary sheet) + 1. If you want to insert new sheets using script, please tell me.
3. It cannot make sheets with same sheet name. So if there are same student names, it is necessary to change a bit.

If you have a script you made for your question, can I ask you about it?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike.  I don't have a script.  I have searched & found scripts that others have made and tried  them & modified with my very limited knowledge.    I have some questions:    
Will it update if someone enters a new student name? I ran the script you provided placing +35 instead of +1, after I typed up the names and it worked great.   I tried it & it made named the last sheet with the revised name.   
 If I copy the sheets, will script be copied along with it?
Will the script run automatically or would I need to run for each sheet that I copy?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since I hadn't had the information of situation you are using this sheet, this script doesn't correspond to most of your new questions. For only one question, when you use this script on spreadsheet, this script can be used by copying spreadsheet. If you want to complete what you want, can I ask you about the detail information you use? If it cannot be published the information, I can use e-mail.